# Is there a better way to check months and days to print the seasons in python? I cant use def and class or loops

Tags: python

I am writing a program that takes a date as input and outputs the date's season. The input is a string to represent the month and an int to represent the day. This is for a school project, while this works it seems a little overkill, is there a better way to get the same results? without using def, class or loops. If not, if you could just let me know its not possible.

```py
input_month = input()
input_day = int(input())

spring = ['March', 'April', 'May', 'June']
summer = ['June', 'July', 'August', 'September']
autumn = ['September', 'October', 'November', 'December']
winter = ['December', 'January', 'February', 'March']
if input_month in spring + summer + autumn + winter:
    if (input_day > 31) or (input_day <= 0):
        print('Invalid')
    elif (input_month == spring[0]) and (input_day >= 20):
        print('Spring')
    elif (input_month == spring[1]) and (input_day <= 30):
        print('Spring')
    elif (input_month == spring[2]) and (input_day >= 31):
        print('Spring')
    elif (input_month == spring[3]) and (input_day <= 20):
        print('Spring')

    elif (input_month == summer[0]) and (input_day >= 21):
        print('Summer')
    elif (input_month == summer[1]) and (input_day <= 31):
        print('Summer')
    elif (input_month == summer[2]) and (input_day <= 31):
        print('Summer')
    elif (input_month == summer[3]) and (input_day <= 21):
        print('Summer')

    elif (input_month == autumn[0]) and (input_day >= 22):
        if input_day >= 31:
            print('Invalid')
        else:
            print('Autumn')
    elif (input_month == autumn[1]) and (input_day <= 31):
        print('Autumn')
    elif (input_month == autumn[2]) and (input_day <= 30):
        print('Autumn')
    elif (input_month == autumn[3]) and (input_day <= 20):
        print('Autumn')

    elif (input_month == winter[0]) and (input_day >= 21):
        print('Winter')
    elif (input_month == winter[1]) and (input_day <= 31):
        print('Winter')
    elif (input_month == winter[2]) and (input_day <= 28):
        print('Winter')
    elif (input_month == winter[3]) and (input_day <= 19):
        print('Winter')
    else:
        print('Invalid')
```

Comment: use three backticks ``` to format your code not three quotes `'''`. I'm not sure about the indentation, are all elif statements the same level of the first if statement or the second one? If it is the first case, this code should produce no result and you should edit to show the correct indentation. Also, minor mistakes like `>=31` for May and `June` can be `31` .

Comment: Boolean expressions don't work like this in Python: `if input_month == spring or summer or autumn or winter`. Because `input_month` is a string, you cannot directly compare its equality to a `list` of strings. Rather, you need to check `if input_month in spring + summer + autumn + winter`. The `+` will concatenate all those lists together into one large list with all the months. Note that there will be duplicates, but that's not really that big a deal.

Comment: I suggest also performing all of your input validation immediately after receiving input from the user, as opposed to sprinkled throughout your core logic.

Comment: can you give me an example, my goal is to see if I can make this simpler. Or if this is an okay way to go about this.

Comment: if I change May and June to 31 then wouldnt that mean if user input was May or June with an int below 31 it would pass because it would be false? I need to allow for dates up to the 31st

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Without using `def` or loops

Yes, there's a much easier way to do this: take advantage of the built-in `dict` data type. You'll need to do some work, but here's *one approach* (out of many) that might help.

### A nicer data structure

```py
seasons = {"January": ("winter",),
           "February": ("winter",),
           "March": ("winter", "spring"),
           "April": ("spring",),
           "May": ("spring",),
           "June": ("spring", "summer"),
           "July": ("summer",),
           "August": ("summer",),
           "September": ("summer", "autumn"),
           "October": ("autumn",),
           "November": ("autumn",),
           "December": ("autumn", "winter")}


# Equinox and solstice dates are a little fuzzy, fiddle with these if you want
transitions = {("winter", "spring"): 21,
               ("spring", "summer"): 21,
               ("summer", "autumn"): 23,
               ("autumn", "winter"): 21}


days_in_month = {"January": 31,
                 "February": 28,  # Not accounting for leap years
                 "March": 31,
                 "April": 30,
                 "May": 31,
                 "June": 30,
                 "July": 31,
                 "August": 31,
                 "September": 30,
                 "October": 31,
                 "November": 30,
                 "December": 31}
```

Now you can get user input

```py
# Get user input
month = input("enter month: ").lower().title()
day = int(input("enter day: "))


# Validate user input
if month not in seasons:
    print("invalid month")
elif not (1 <= day <= days_in_month[month]):
    print("invalid day")
```

One issue here is that if the month is invalid, the program doesn't do anything about it.

### The algorithm

Now, using the two `seasons` and `transitions` dictionaries, implement this algorithm (I'll leave this part up to you):

1. Get the "season" by accessing the `season` dictionary with a key whose value is `month`. This `dict` returns either a 1-tuple or a 2-tuple, depending on whether there's a seasonal transition that `month`.
2. If the `tuple` returned by the `season` lookup is a 1-tuple (check its length), you can directly return the first value in that `tuple`, which will be the correct season for that month, and you're done. If not, proceed to step 3.
3. If the `tuple` returned by the `season` lookup is a 2-tuple, use that `tuple` as the key in the `transitions` dictionary. This will return an integer, the day the season transition occurs, which you can call `t_day`.
4. Compare the `day` to `t_day`. If `day` is less than `t_day`, return the first item in the 2-tuple. Otherwise return the second.
5. Done!

### Example:

If `month = March`, then `season` will be `("winter", "spring")`. Since the length of the `season` tuple is 2, lookup the `t_day`, which will be `21` since the spring equinox is generally considered to occur on March 21. Suppose now that `day = 13`. Since 13 is not greater than or equal to 21, return `season[0]`, which is `"winter"`.

### Solution

Since other people are just giving you answers straight up, I suppose I can provide my own (I was hoping to encourage you to figure the basic algorithm out on your own):

```py
season = seasons.get(month)
transition_day = transitions.get(season, 99)
season = season[day >= transition_day]
```

This follows roughly the same logic that I laid out in the algorithm section, but takes advantage of the fact that `bool` is a subclass of `int`, meaning you can subscript sequences using boolean values, e.g.: `"ab"[False] -> "a"` (since `False == 0`).

By using `.get()` on the `transition_day` dictionary and providing a fallback value, we can simply subscript the `season` tuple (which is either 1 or 2 elements) using the boolean check `day >= transition_day`. If that boolean condition is `True`, we return `season[1]`, otherwise we return `season[0]`.

The reason this works even when `season` only has one element is because of that `.get()` which returns `99` if the key `season` isn't present in the `transitions` dictionary. This ensures that `day >= transition_day` will always be `False` when `transition_day` is `99`, which means that you're guaranteed to always only ever call `season[False] == season[0]` in the case that `season` is only a 1-tuple.

## Opening up to using `def` and loops

By using `def`, you can define functions which separate the logic of your code into isolated pieces which all perform a single task. This helps massively in keeping code clean, organized, and easy to reason about.

By using a `while` loop, you can ensure that the user input is always valid and that your code won't proceed *until the user provides valid input*.

### A better way to deal with user input

Here's a freebie. There's a lot going on here, so take your time understanding what these two functions do:

```py
def get_month():
    while True:
        month = input("enter month: ").lower().title()
        if month not in seasons:
            print("invalid month!")
            continue
        return month


def get_day(max_days):
    while True:
        try:
            day = int(input("enter day: "))
        except ValueError:
            print("invalid entry, day must be an integer!")
            continue
        if not (1 <= day <= max_days):
            print(f"invalid day, must be between 1 and {max_days}")
            continue
        return day
```

### Encapsulating the `season` logic

You can do the same thing with the logic for determining the `season`:

```py
def get_season(month, day):
    season = seasons.get(month)
    transition_day = transitions.get(season, 99)
    return season[day >= transition_day]
```

Then your main script is reduced to three function calls:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Get user input
    month = get_month()
    day = get_day(max_days=days_in_month[month])
    
    # Get season
    season = get_season(month, day)
    print(f"{month}, {day}: {season}")
```

### Notes

With this solution, we've reduced the 40 lines of code it took to perform this task using `if-elif-else` down to a mere three lines of code (for the core logic of determining the season).

By wrapping your logic in a function,

```py
def get_season(month, day):
    season = seasons.get(month)
    transition_day = transitions.get(season, 99)
    return season[day >= transition_day]
```

You now have three explicitly named functions: `get_month()`, `get_day()`, and `get_season()`. These functions make it abundantly clear what task each one of these functions performs. This is something you want to think about when writing scripts or designing software. It's also known as the [single responsibility principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-responsibility_principle) and is an *extremely* important part of programming.

Finally, to test this function and ensure that it is working properly, you can use this little snippet to enumerate all 365 days of the year:

```py
for month, max_days in days_in_month.items():
    for day in range(1, max_days + 1):
        season = get_season(month, day)
        print(f"{month}, {day}: {season}")
    print()
```

Comment: This is great, I just haven't learned loops of defs yet, that's next week. Also with the max days if a user inputted say 43, would that return an error or work, I need to make sure they cant enter more than 31 for the day.

Comment: With the `get_month` and `get_day` functions, no, the program won't proceed until the user provides valid input.

Comment: But in the first code snippet where I defined the dictionaries, there's some very basic input validation.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying, this does seem to cover most of the material I have learned so far. I also appreciate the section on Opening up to using def and loops. Ill have to look at this more next week when we cover it.

Comment: @DerekPruitt if my answer helped you, would you be so kind as to accept it (by clicking the check mark)? That way, your question will be removed from the unanswered queue. Glad I could help!

Answer (score 2):

To check if input day is inside valid range, a dictionary is helpful to map each month and days in that month. To check which season the input is belong to, you may try to compare days in year after converting season boundaries and input to that.

```
month_days = {
    "January": 31, "February": 28, "March": 31, "April": 30,
    "May": 31, "June": 30, "July": 31, "August": 31,
    "September": 30, "October": 31, "November": 30, "December": 31
}

# cummulative year days at the start of that month
cum_year_days = {}
summ = 0
for m, d in month_days.items():
    cum_year_days[m] = summ
    summ += d

# Or you can hard coded it like month_days
# cum_year_days = {
#     'January': 0, 'February': 31, 'March': 59, 'April': 90, 
#     'May': 120, 'June': 151, 'July': 181, 'August': 212, 
#     'September': 243, 'October': 273, 'November': 304, 'December': 334
# }

month = input("Month: ")
day = int(input("Day: "))

if month in month_days and 1 <= day <= month_days[month]:
    # convert input to year days
    year_days = cum_year_days[month] + day
    # convert season boundaries to year days in similar way
    if cum_year_days["March"] + 20 <= year_days <= cum_year_days["June"] + 20:
        print("Spring")
    elif cum_year_days["June"] + 21 <= year_days <= cum_year_days["September"] + 21:
        print("Summer")
    elif cum_year_days["September"] + 22 <= year_days <= cum_year_days["December"] + 20:
        print("Autumn")
    else:
        print("Winter")
else:
    print("Invalid")
```

Notes on your code and details on my comment:

1. In your original code, you have a line `input_month == spring or summer or autumn or winter`. You have changed it but I want to explain why it is wrong. It is read as `(input_month == spring) or summer or autumn or winter`, the first one compares equality between string and a list so it will be `False`, and non-empty list is truthy so the following condition will return `True`. Therefore, it is `True` because you have non-empty list instead of valid input.
2. For May, you have condition `input_day >= 31`, so May 1 to 30 are all invalid. It should be `<=`.
3. For June, you have condition `input_day >= 21` and restriction from the first if statement `input_day > 31`, so June 21 to June 31 are all valid, while June has no 31.
   You may check it like `21 <= input_day <= 30`.

---

I found out that using tuple to represent date and performing tuple comparison may be more intuitive.

```
month_days = {
    "January": (1, 31), "February": (2, 28), "March": (3, 31), "April": (4, 30),
    "May": (5, 31), "June": (6, 30), "July": (7, 31), "August": (8, 31),
    "September": (9, 30), "October": (10, 31), "November": (11, 30), "December": (12, 31)
}

month = input("Month: ")
day = int(input("Day: "))

if month in month_days and 1 <= day <= month_days[month][1]:
    # convert input to date
    date = (month_days[month][0], day)
    # convert season boundaries to date
    if (3, 20) <= date <= (6, 20):
        print("Spring")
    elif (6, 21) <= date <= (9, 21):
        print("Summer")
    elif (9, 22) <= date <= (12, 20):
        print("Autumn")
    else:
        print("Winter")
else:
    print("Invalid")
```

Tuples compare lexicographically, that is compare element by element, return result immediately when they are not equal. In this case, it will check the month first, earlier month with lower value will be `<` later month. If months are equal, it will check the day, ealier day with lower value will be `<` later day. If both are equals, they are `==`.

Comment: FWIW, OP states that they don't want to use loops.

Comment: this is great, I just cant use loops because we havent learned them yet. is there a way to get around the loop, but still keep the code small?

Comment: @DerekPruitt The only for loop part is the calculation of cumulative year days, and you can just hard coded it as shown in my code comment.

Comment: @DerekPruitt I also add an alternative using tuple for your reference.